# Вызов одного метода у комбинированного делегата в C#

Tags: c#, делегаты

Можно ли в С# у комбинированных делегатов вызывать один конкретный метод?

Comment: Так смысл делегата как раз в том, чтобы Наблюдаемый объект ничего не знал о Наблюдателях (один ли он или несколько, а может и вообще ни одного)...

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно что-то другое, может что-то типа `List<Action<>>`...

Comment: Который из?....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью метода [GetInvocationList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist(v=vs.110).aspx) можно получить массив делегатов, составляющий список вызовов текущего делегата.

Конкретный делегат из этого списка и будет конкретным методом комбинированного делегата.

Например:

```
Action action = () => Console.Write("1");
action += () => Console.Write("2");
action += () => Console.Write("3");

action.GetInvocationList()[1].DynamicInvoke();
```

Выведет в консоль `2`.

Comment: И чем вам не нравится решение, или не понятно написано? Вполне хорошо.